# Run two flash applications in a dual screen setup

Tags: flash

I have a Adobe Flash application that runs full screen in kiosk mode (as projector exe) and is mirrored onto a second screen through simple OS based cloning of the screen (Windows 7).

Now there's a requirement that instead of simply cloning the first screen, the application should show other additional information on the second screen.

My naive approach was to create two separate Flash applications and let them communicate over a http proxy. However I haven't found anything in the API in the Adobe Flash documentation that allows me to send the secondary application **fullscreen** onto the **second** monitor.

Does anyone have an idea? Or is it easier/possible to have one application (instead of two) but with double the width? Would that stretch over to both screens?

Update: A LocalConnection as mentioned by Ryan below is simpler than a http proxy, so I went that route. For the dual screen problem, I used the Flash Builder tool mentioned below.

Comment: A Good question! and one I'd love to find a better solution to.  In the past, I have used visual studio and embeded both swf's in different form windows, and used `ExternalInterface` in AS3 to communicate to the underlying VisualStudio code, which acts as the middleman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. This little tool here converts swfs to headless executables and has some neat features to access the filesystem and interact with the flash file.

http://thesz.diecru.eu/content/flash.php

```
fscommand("exec","app.exe"); - executes a file which is located in the fscommand subdirectory
fscommand("real_exec","app.exe"); - executes a file which is in the same directory as the executable
fscommand("set_title","Window Title"); - sets the window title
fscommand("quit",""); - exit the flash
fscommand("command","move"); on MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN / fscommand("command","mouse_up"); on MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP - drag the window
fscommand("command","resize"); on MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN / fscommand("command","mouse_up"); on MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP - resize the window
fscommand("position","save"); / fscommand("position","restore"); / fscommand("position","clear"); - save, restore and clear window position
```

The developer was so kind to extend the command set with

```
fscommand("position","100x200 300x400"); // position, then size (optional)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you need is LocalConnection. This enables two flash files (i know it works for swf, never tried the projector exe files) to communicate, pass variables and work together. If i'm understanding your question correctly, this would work ideally for you.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html

http://circlecube.com/2008/03/local-connection-actionscript-communicate-between-seperate-flash-files-tutorial/

both files need to be on the same server or in the same folder locally. Testing from within flash won't work either since the two files then become dependent upon one another, which makes testing a little difficult. Personally, I can't help too much with it as I've only used LC for very basic things like passing variables and initiating tweens. Hope that helps!